# Prove the following inequality for all positive real numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$

Tags: inequality

Prove the following inequality for all positive real numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{a+b+d}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{def}{c+e+f}}<\sqrt[3]{(a+b+d)(c+e+f)}$$ I tried to cube both sides and rearranging the terms but it wasn't of any help. Is there any theorm of inequality which proves this or we have to do this by cubing and rearranging the terms. In either case please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be AM-GM as follows
$$
\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{a+b+d}\cdot \frac{b}{a+b+d} \cdot \frac{c}{c+e+f}} \le \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a}{a+b+d} + \frac{b}{a+b+d} + \frac{c}{c+e+f}\right) 
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[3]{\frac{d}{a+b+d}\cdot \frac{e}{c+e+f} \cdot \frac{f}{c+e+f}} \le \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{d}{a+b+d} + \frac{e}{c+e+f} + \frac{f}{c+e+f}\right) 
$$
Adding these side by side, we have

$$
\sqrt[3]{\frac{d}{a+b+d}\cdot \frac{e}{c+e+f} \cdot \frac{f}{c+e+f}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{a+b+d}\cdot \frac{b}{a+b+d} \cdot \frac{c}{c+e+f}} \le \frac{2}{3} < 1
$$
This completes the proof  $~\blacksquare$.

Comment: Can you clarify your method

Comment: It's AM-GM for 3 positive numbers
$$
\sqrt[3]{abc} \le \frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)
$$

Comment: How will this prove the statement

Comment: I understood thanks